# iPhone grouped table view cell reuse

Tags: iphone, reusability, grouped-table

My iPhone programs frequently contain grouped table views.  A typical use might be for settings.  The number of rows in these table views can run anywhere from roughly 2 to 20.  The cells typically don't have a lot of uniformity.

Should I be trying to reuse the cells?  If so, how much commonality do cells need to have to get a shared identifier?  For example, consider two cells with the same size, with one containing a label and a text input field; the other containing two labels and a slider.  Or is this just not worth the bother?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you release all your cells properly, you don't need to reuse cells because all your cells are different.